# Is this a right magnetics termination for PoE and non-PoE application

Tags: voltage, capacitor, transformer, ethernet, termination

I came across the below schematic image while trying to read Bob-smith termination.

Would there be any problems with the termination on the right side with and without PoE?

Can someone explain a little on how the termination is different from Bob-smith and why?

[image]

Comment: Freshman - Hi, You said that you "*came across the below schematic image*". Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, the original content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Please can you edit your question to include the required source link for the original image? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No. That's not correct. It does not terminate.

There is an AC short circuit between center taps.

If you compare with Bob Smith, it has impedance between center tap, either DC or AC coupled.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, this type of termination will not work for PoE as well, right? Could you tell me what's the right way to terminate the centre taps? Are the other bottom resistors and capacitors fine? Thanks in advance again.

Comment: It is not useful to ask about PoE or what's right about this, as there is nothing to power via PoE. Sure this is wrong and it may work with PoE, but it depends on which type of PoE you mean - Nothing will burn if passive PoE feeds a supply, there is just nothing to be powered. A true PoE source would not give PoE out as your schematics have no way to negotiate PoE.

Comment: Thank you. "Nothing will burn if passive PoE feeds a supply", you mean, this will feed a supply? I want to have a PoE port connected to this. Can you give me a suggestion on how to terminate the centre taps?

Comment: Your design has nothing to use power fed by PoE. I can't know how you are going to implement PoE. There are hundreds of application notes how to do Ethernet and how to do PoE. They show how to do it right.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Leaving aside PoE, could you tell me apart from the AC short, how to modify the termination arrangement on the right side of magnetics?

Comment: You should consult the documentation for your PHY for that.

Comment: the documentation refers to the Bob-smith termination only.